# How do I prove whether or not a dining philosophers suffers from deadlock or starvation possibilities? Where to start?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

I have a homework task to prove whether or not a particular variation on the dining philosophers problem suffers from deadlock or starvation.  I suspect that the situation does not suffer at all from either but I'm finding this tricky to prove and I don't really know where to start.  Is there a general strategy for attacking this sort of problem?

Comment: Ask the person who set the homework. You are paying them, directly or indirectly.

Comment: Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Problem ?  Testing for deadlock is deadsimple.

Comment: @James. This depends on the nature of the variation a little bit. It might not have fixed behaviour for all philosophers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about [Wait-for graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait-for_graph) (more details [here](http://www.cis.temple.edu/~ingargio/cis307/readings/deadlock.html)) which are DAGs (Directed Acyclic Graphs) and are used to detect deadlocks.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

For a start, I would be very surprised to hear there is a general strategy to solve the problem which is not so abstract as to be useless.

Now, *showing* the variation is safe is much, much easier than *proving* it: your task is to *prove* the variation is safe? If so, you might minimize the number of parts (reduce the number of philosophers to two or maybe three) and try ta apply one or more [formal verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) methods.

In practice, formal verification is so rare that I might illustrate it best with an example: I've talked with people working on software used in nuclear facilities (haven't gone into the details) and when I asked if they use formal verification, I got "well, yes, we should [be using it]..."